# iOS: Why is the ViewController called when the app runs in background mode after terminated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, background, core-location

I made an application that monitors updated location in background after terminated like Moves.
In order to implement this app, I made a location manager class including `<CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>` and `CLLocationManagerDelegate` and enabled 'Location updates' and 'Background fetch' modes in Capabilities. And in order for checking out, I added a node.js module which is connected to remote server, and this application send a message to remote server when new location is updated in background (after terminated, not remained in suspended apps queue).
And the location manager is declared and called in `viewDidLoad` of ViewController.

The question is why is the ViewController called when the app runs in background mode after terminated like above flow?
I just thought that the location manager would be called only because it contains `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, but I was wrong. The background task started from `viewDidLoad` method.

Dose anybody know why is this happened? I really want to know which functions are called from the beginning in background mode after terminated.

**EDIT:**

Here are my codes for updating current location in background after terminated. I also added capabilities which are 'Location updates' and 'Background fetch'.

1. ViewController.m (`viewDidLoad` method)

   `[super viewDidLoad];`

   locationManager = [[LocationManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
   UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
   switch(state){
       case UIApplicationStateActive:
       case UIApplicationStateInactive:
           [locationManager startLocationService:NO];
           break;
       case UIApplicationStateBackground:
           [locationManager startLocationService:YES];
           break;
   }
2. LocationManager.m (`init` method)

   `isCalledAfterTerminated = flag;
   if(!socketIO.isConnected){
       [socketIO connect];
   }
   locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
   if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]){
       [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
   }
   // for iOS 9
   if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:)]){
       [locationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];
   }
   locationManager.delegate = self;
   locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
   if(isCalledAfterTerminated){
       locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
       locationManager.distanceFilter = DISTANCE_FILTER_TERMINATED;
       [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
   } else {
       locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
       locationManager.distanceFilter = DISTANCE_FILTER_RUNNING;
       [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
   }`

Comment: Please provide code

Comment: @pckill Sorry. It contains a lot of confidential information, so I couldn't provide my codes that I wrote for this test. If you couldn't understand without any of codes, I'll write a core function for it.

Comment: Ok, so my guess is that you have a reference to the view controller somewhere in your background code. If that does not help, try to strip all the confidential parts from your code and provide us with an example illustrating the problem.

Comment: You simply require debugging help for your problem. You should read 3 docs: [UIApplicationDelegate Overview in _API Reference_](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate), [Background Execution section of _App Programming Guide for iOS_](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html), and The App Life Cycle section of the same guide.